# How to transfer touch and immediately use it on the view

Tags: ios, swift, touch, send, touch-event

I'm new to the swift and I have a problem, I need to create the same picture in the view (I can use the gesture) by clicking on the picture and move it without releasing the finger, I can not transmit the touch on the view, how to do it, I created the block

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    self.touchBeganBlock?()
}


 cell.touchBeganBlock = {

        self.hiddenView.isHidden = false
        self.hiddenView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        self.hiddenView.frame = CGRect(x: 110, y: 530, width: 194, height: 137)
        self.redactingImage.image = UIImage(named: self.arrayOfImages[indexPath.row])
        self.redactingImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    }
```

In which I perform the show and set the parameters, it is executed only after clicking on the created view,but it is necessary that I can move the picture for the first touch with my finger

Comment: Check out [UIGestureRecognizers](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uigesturerecognizer). You should rarely need to use `touchesBegan`

Comment: Here I am forced to use it since the very same touch does not happen, we just touch the screen and without releasing a finger there make a view which we immediately too, not releasing a finger, we can move

Comment: For such a case, I'd suggest to check how could it be done via [UIPan​Gesture​Recognizer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipangesturerecognizer) instead of working with `touchesBegan` method.

Comment: i also use it, but i cant send my touch to my hiddenView (

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `hitTest` to pass touch to another view.

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    if condition {
        return currentView.hitTest(currentView.convert(point, from: self), with: event)
    }
    return underneathView.hitTest(underneathView.convert(point, from: self), with: event)
}
```